# Navbar remian constant for all pages in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new to jquery mobile and need some help to move further in my application

I used NAVBAR with two buttons view and two buttons are navigating fine and displaying different list views & when I click on list view item the page is navigating to another HTML page and displaying related data but the problem is I'm not able to view navbar in next page...

I want the navbar to be constant for all pages like tabgroup activity in android.
anyone please help me with good example and application or show me some good links to achieve this...

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="navbar" id="nav1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-href="dashboard" class="ui-btn-active" datafld="list">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-href="deals" datafld="list1">Deals</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-but" id="list">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a  href="#lv1" data-role="button" id="button1" >
                    <img src="task.png" alt="Tasks" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <a  href="#lv2" data-role="button" id="button2">
                    <img src="reminder.png" alt="Reminders" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="def_content_div" id="dashboard">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="#lv1">List View 1</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#lv2" >List View 2</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#lv3" >List View 3</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#lv4" >List View 4</a> </li>
             </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content_div" id="deals">
                <ul data-role="listview"data-inset="true">
                    <li> <a href="#lv5">List View 5</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#lv6">List View 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#lv7">List View 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#lv8">List View 8</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: I have posted my html code.hope now u get some idea what i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to put your navbar inside a JQM header and use the same data-id for every header. i.e.

```
<div data-role="header" data-posistion="fixed" data-id="constantNav">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-href="dashboard" class="ui-btn-active" datafld="list">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-href="deals" datafld="list1">Deals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You have to include the above code snippet in every listview page. That will give the appearance of a constant fixed nav menu.

Here is an example as requested http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/z5VYF/1/

Comment: Hi codaniel thanks for your response but it's not worked for me

Comment: Give me more code then please. What does your listview pages look like?

Comment: Hi can u please have a look at the image in this link http://www.pocketmagic.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/android_tab_control_2.jpg  I want something like this as in image.I got tabs and different listview under each tab.When i select an item from list it showing the details in other page but the tabs are not visible only data is visible and i want the tabs to be visible in all pages...hope i'm able to give u some idea now

Comment: I think I can help you but what I am curious about is how your code looks in the "next" page as you refer to it. Are you just putting nothing but a listview in that page? You have to include the header in each of those pages.

Comment: Ok well that is the problem. It has to be included in each JQM page.

Comment: oh can u please provide me some examples in detail

Comment: Ok I added an example at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: hi codaniel thanks for ur previous code it helped me a lot.Can u plz help with me with one more thing? My question is the code u've given in  http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/z5VYF/1/ when we select an item say list1 it showing all list items that's fine but problem is when we select deals tab from there i'm able to get the items of deals tab but it showing dashboard tab as active..hope you understood my question can u plz help me..

Comment: Yeah remove this throughout your code `class="ui-btn-active"`. It should help you out.

Comment: yah that's ok but now i'm not able to see the dashboard as selected at starting

Comment: hi codaniel can you explain me one more thing?? How do u getting the loading symbol for onclick of every new page is there any js or css file for the example you given??

Comment: i posted a new question in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331729/loading-symbol-for-onclick-of-every-new-data-role-page-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from [http://jquerymobile.com/demos](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html)

According to codaniel's answer, we need to include the code snippet in every listview page.

And then, we need to add the following class to the "current" nav-button of every page.

```
class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist"
```

For the first front page:

```
<div data-role="header" data-posistion="fixed" data-id="constantNav">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-href="dashboard" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" datafld="list">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-href="deals" datafld="list1">Deals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the second page:

```
<div data-role="header" data-posistion="fixed" data-id="constantNav">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-href="dashboard"  datafld="list">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-href="deals" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" datafld="list1">Deals</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```